# Only send email if disk usages exceeds 80%

Tags: shell, disk, mailx

My script is:

```
abc=$(df -h | sed s/%//g | awk '{ if($5 > 80) print "Alert "$0;}' | awk '{print $2,$6}') \
    && echo -e "Dear All, \n\n$abc\n\nABC" \
     | mailx -s "Disk partition" support@something.com
```

Here when condition is not true, I get the following output in my email:

```
Filesystem Use
```

However I want mail only when disk usage exceeds 80%.

Comment: Did you consider enabling disk quotas? BTW, did you read documentation of [GNU awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)? You probably should use it once (no need for your pipeline) and invoke `mailx` *inside* your `awk` script

Answer (score 1):

Recommend using a) mulitliners for such things, b) to check 'nagios' and co.
For the first try, check out this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function chk () {
        # declare as integer to  be used in arithmetic expressions
        declare -i usage
        echo "checking mount $1. has $2 percent"
        usage=$2

        if [[ ${usage} -gt 80 ]] ; then 
                echo "alert for partition $1"
                #echo -e "Dear ..." | mailx -s "Disk partition ..." 
        fi
}
df -h | grep -v "none" | tail -n +2 | sed s/%//g | while read a b c d e f; 
        do chk $a $e;
```

done